# Error when docker start some container

Tags: docker

```
# docker start 039e6a890501

Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 039e6a890501: mkdir /sys/fs/cpuset: operation not permitted

FATA[0000] Error: failed to start one or more containers
```

Comment: did you see the error message `operation not permitted`?

Comment: Which architecture are running on? Can you add the output of `uname -a` to the question?